# How do you test for diagonal in n-queens?

Tags: c++, n-queens

I'm studying the n-queen backtracker. Can someone explain to me how `other_row_pos` checks for diagonals? I'm not sure why it works or how it works.

taken from wikibooks - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/N-Queens:

```
bool isSafe(int queen_number, int row_position) {
    // Check each queen before this one
    for(int i=0; i<queen_number; i++) {
        // Get another queen's row_position
        int other_row_pos = position[i];
        // Now check if they're in the same row or diagonals
        if(other_row_pos == row_position || // Same row
           other_row_pos == row_position - (queen_number-i) || // Same diagonal
           other_row_pos == row_position + (queen_number-i))   // Same diagonal
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Diagonals are lines of slope ±1...

Comment: its checking whether the new queen can be inserted to a position without attacking other queen

Comment: In the link provided, i noticed there is no way to do the UNDO of the assignment of position[i]? Where is the backtracker in this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let `delta_row` = the difference in rows between the two queens, and `delta_col` = the difference in columns. The two queens will be on the same diagonal if `delta_row == delta_col` or `delta_row == -delta_col`.

With the variables you have:

```
delta_row = other_row_pos - row_position
delta_col = queen_number - i
```

So the queens are on the same diagonal if:

```
other_row_pos - row_position == queen_number - i ||
other_row_pos - row_position == -(queen_number - i)
```

If you add `row_position` to both sides of the equality, you get the condition in your code:

```
other_row_pos == row_position + (queen_number-i) ||
other_row_pos == row_position - (queen_number-i)
```

Comment: Or even `abs(other_row_pow - row_position) == abs(queen_number - i)` if one prefers that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you have to check if board element (x,y) can be attacked from any diagonal element or not. (x,y) can be attacked diagonally if any element lying on its diagonal element is a queen.Assume (p,q) is board element having a queen.Now condition for element(x,y) to lie on diagonal coordinates of board element (p,q) would be p+q == x+y or p-q == x-y .This can also be interpreted as the condition for elements (p,q) and (x,y) to lie on same diagonal.So, if there is queen at (p,q) and we have to check whether (x,y) can be attacked by this queen or not, the condition for this would be:-

```
            if((board[p][q] == 1 ) && ((p+q == x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true; 
            }
```

Complete function for checking if element at (x,y) i.e., board[x,y] is attacked by diagonal elements or not would be:-

```
for(int p=1;p<board.length;p++){
        for(int q=1;q<board.length;q++){

            if(p==x && q==y){   //skipping check if element under consideration is same
                continue;
            }

            if((board[p][q] == 1 )&& ((p+q == x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Complete function for checking if element (x,y) is attacked or not would be:-

```
    public static boolean is_attacked(int x,int y,int board[][],int n){
    for(int i = 1;i < board.length;i++){
        if(board[x][i] == 1){            //if any cell in xth row is 1 i.e.,queen is there in that row
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1;i < board.length;i++){     
        if(board[i][y] == 1){         //if any cell in yth column is 1 i.e.,queen is there in that column
            return true;
        }
    }
    for(int p=1;p<board.length;p++){
        for(int q=1;q<board.length;q++){

            if(p==x && q==y){
                continue;
            }

            if((board[p][q]== 1 )&& ((p+q== x+y) || (p-q == x-y))){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!!!